# Retrieving Firebase Twitter Auth tokens after initial sign in

Tags: firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth

Just following the [firebase twitter auth guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/twitter-login?authuser=0) and I'm curious if there is a way to retrieve the twitter accessToken and secret after the first sign in.

You can retrieve these after logging in the first time with

```
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function (result) {
        if (result.credential) {
            // This gives you a the Twitter OAuth 1.0 Access Token and Secret.
            // You can use these server side with your app's credentials to access the Twitter API.
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            var secret = result.credential.secret;
            console.log([token, secret]);
            // ...
        }
        // The signed-in user info.
        var user = result.user;
        //console.log(user);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        var email = error.email;
        // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
        var credential = error.credential;
        // ...
    });
```

However, based on my understanding, this is only run the first time after logging in with Twitter.

How can I retrieve their twitter accessToken and secret when they open the page again? Should I store them when I get them the first time?

Comment: You can't. Firebase Auth does not store these credentials. If you need them for later use, you would need to programmatically store them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Firebase Auth does not store these credentials. If you need them for later use, you would need to programmatically store them after first sign-in. You could use Firebase realtime database/Firestore to do so but make sure that they can only be accessed by the corresponding authenticated user or not publicly accessible if you plan to use them server side.